# Use all files in a folder like a one big JS

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint

Is it possible to configure ESLint in WebStorm so functions, variables, etc. are parsed also from files in the same folder? In my build process, I concatenate all files in the same folders into big closures, for example:

```
   src/
      main/          ===> "main.js"
          api.js
          init.js
          ui.js
          constants.js
          .
          .
      renderer/      ===> "renderer.js"
          core.js
          events.js
```

I would like ESLint to treat all those files just like one, so I don't get "undef" errors for things that are defined.

If it can't be done automatically, I wouldn't mind to create a manual configuration specifying all those files if that is possible.

**EDIT**: Why I don't (can't) use modules? TLDR- legacy code and project requirements.

- I need to minify all code. Current closure compiler can transpile ES6 into ES5, but I found some ES6 features very prone to produce broken code. So I am forced to use ES5.
- As I need ES5. I would only be able to use `require()` to use modules. Now that's a problem, as require() is a dynamic include and it impacts performance on my context (big electron app for modest power devices)

So to answer @Avin_Kavish, I agree what I do is "technically non conforming", but at the end of the build process it is, because each folder has been grouped into a file. That file is the module or the script. To group the files I use a Gradle plugin https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin, I inject a "closure header" and a "closure footer", and all the files in between in the order I want.

Despite the inconvenience, at the end I get super-compact nodeJS code, with all methods obfuscated, etc.

I ended up using @Patrick suggestion, thanks for that!

**EDIT 2**

WebPack + Electron-WebPack turned out to be what I was looking for.

BTW- I think the proper way to do this is if EsLint would allow a "folder" sourceType.

Comment: You can use ES6 module syntax and stay away from all the other ES6 features: after bundling to a single script, you get valid ES5.

Comment: I am using pure ES5 at the moment, got really frightened with stupid closure compiler errors popping out in random places, I'm also exploring Babel, looks like it supports ES6 better than Google CC. Do yo uhave experience with it?

Comment: I think you don't even need Babel, a bundler like webpack or rollup will suffice for handling module syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide code examples in your question, but I assume you do something like this:

*api.js*

```
const api = {
  fetchData() {
    // some code that fetches data
  }
};
```

*core.js*

```
const core = {
  init() {
    api.fetchData();
  }
};
```

The ESLint rule that causes errors when you lint these JavaScript modules is the [no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) rule.

It checks for variables that are used without having been defined. In the code example *core.js* above, this would be `api`, because that is defined in another module, which ESLint doesn't know about.

You don't care about these errors, because in your actual JS bundle used in production, the code from *api.js* and *core.js* is concatenated in one bundle, so `api` will be defined.

So actually `api` in this example is a global variable.

The `no-undef` rule allows you to define global variables so that they won't cause errors.

There are two ways to do this:

**Using Comments**

At the beginning of your *core.js* module, add this line:

```
/* global api */
```

**Using the ESLint Config**

As explained [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) – add this to your *.eslintrc* file:

```
{
  "globals": {
    "api": "writable"
  }
}
```

**Side Note**

As some commenters to your question pointed out, it would probably be better to use [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) statements in the modules, together with a module bundling tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) to create one bundle from your JavaScript modules.

Comment: Hey Patrick thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I would like ESlint to discover them itself from files in the same folder, but as it looks like it's not possible, this solution works for me. Unfortunately I cannot use impot/export/require as you can read in the edited question !

Comment: Glad to help. I still believe webpack would be a great solution for you, you can use it to handle import/export statements and it has a minification plugin.

Comment: Sure it is! Just learnt about it yesterday, and looks like it basically automates what I am doing manually. I don't fancy rewriting all the build process at the moment, but for next versions looks the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

A physical JavaScript file with an import/export statement is a **module** by the standard. A single .js file without import/export is  a **script** by the standard. What you are trying to do is non-conforming to this, there is no specification in ECMAScript that allows splitting a single script or module across several files. I do get where you are coming from, for example: C# has partial classes that allows you to split a class across multiple files. But trying to replicate this without a standard syntax is not wise. Especially, when import/export can and will do the job for you

For example, with the following assumptions, your `main.js` can be refactored to,

```
constants.js // <--- constants
ui.js  // <--- logic to build UI
api.js  // <--- exposing public api
init.js  // <--- setup code before use

// main.js 
// If you name this index.js you can import it as 'src/main' instead of 'src/main/main.js'
import { A,B } from './constants'
import { api } from './api'
import { displayUi } from './ui'
import { init } from './init'

init(A);
displayUi(B);

export { api } // <-- re-expose public api
```

Comment: Hi Avin, thanks for your detailed answer. I would really love to be able to use that, unfortunately i am tied to ES5 for this project.  Your answer would be the best way to do it, I think.